# ERROR 1970 ER_SUBPROCESS_TIMEOUT_ERROR: Subprocess timed out when creating a pipeline

Tags: database, error-handling, pipeline, singlestore

Running into a bit of an issue when creating pipelines:

CREATE PIPELINE library
AS LOAD DATA S3 ''
CONFIG '{"region": "eu-west-1"}'
CREDENTIALS '{"aws_access_key_id": "", "aws_secret_access_key": ""}'
INTO TABLE `test`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';

ERROR 1970 ER_SUBPROCESS_TIMEOUT_ERROR: Subprocess timed out. Truncated stderr:

Upon failure, the command.log on the aggregator says:

1958097856 2019-02-05 09:58:25.114  ERROR: write() system call (fd=11) failed with errno: 32 (Broken pipe)
1958097903 2019-02-05 09:58:25.114  ERROR: NotifyAndClose(): Failed writing back to the engine

Answer (score 1):

First of all, can we quickly confirm you are on 6.5 or later? If you are on an earlier version, it might be worth upgrading, since S3 pipelines have been significantly improved since then. If you can’t upgrade, you might have to bump pipelines_extractor_get_offsets_timeout_ms, but in 6.5 or later, this should not be necessary.
Otherwise, it could be a bonified a connectivity issue. Make sure the Master Aggregator can connect to your ceph node.